# Append Rows to existing Excel document using Laravel-Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpexcel

I have an existing Excel document, to which I want to append some data using [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel). The package has nice documentation but unfortunately there is no full example showing how to do that, but only partial demonstration of manipulating rows.

What I am attempting to do is:

1. open the existing document
2. get the first sheet, append new
3. close the document

The code:

```
Excel::load($path . '/exported.xls', function($reader){
                    $sheet = $reader->getActiveSheet();
                    // Manipulate third row
                    $sheet->row(3, array(
                            'test1', 'test2'
                        ));
                });
```

Which results in

> Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::row()

Has anyone succeeded appending data with this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it is not possible to edit an Excel file like I intended to.
Source: [package creator](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/208).

Answer (score 4):

Laravel Excel 1.2.0 added support for appending rows (so modifying existing Excel files)

http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#edit

The correct code would be:

```
Excel::load($path . '/exported.xls', function($reader)
{
    $reader->sheet(function($sheet) 
    {
        // Manipulate third row
        $sheet->row(3, array(
            'test1', 'test2'
        ));
    });
})->export('xls');
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you would use...

```
$sheet->appendRow(array(
    'appended', 'appended'
));
```

Found in the docs here... http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export

Comment: That does not work either... I forgot to mention that I already tried that out. `Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::appendRow()`